# python flask test site not working on IIS server, however it works on localhost

Tags: python-3.x, iis, fastcgi

I have been given access to an IIS server
Windows 2012 R2
IIS version 8.5.9600

I successfully installed
python 3.8
wfastcgi
flask

i wrote a basic "hello world" python flask app which i tested and works on the localhost machine

I created my web.config file and has the following

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="C:\Python36\python.exe|C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
           resourceType="Unspecified"
           requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <!-- Required settings -->
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="hello.app" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_site" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

For this site i enabled IISUsers to have Modify and Write access

I am unable to load the site though.  Am i missing anything in the configuration?

When i click on IIS, FasCTI Settings appears and properly points to the python.
I am getting a 500 error in the logs.

help is alwasy appreciated.

Best

DamnGroundHog

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like i have everything correct but i decided to play around with some settings, specifically bindings.

when i changed the port from 80 to 8080 and took the host name away, it worked. Yay!  Now i will look at bindings and see why my basic index.html worked but the hello.py didn't

Answer (score 0):

Through my restoration of a project similar to your python project, it can be successfully run on the window server. I follow this tutorial, you can refer to it.

[Detail steps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/how-to-run-python-application-on-iis-that-uses-flask-framework/ba-p/812898)

In the process of my application, it only works when the port is also 8080 because the application is deployed under the default website. At the same time index.html works because the default document is set, you can check your default document module.